# angular ng-include does not parse ui-view

Tags: javascript, angularjs, plunker

I learn AngularJS
and I stuck on this moment: [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/XD6CJPRH1PDrrKVyWorp?p=preview)

I try toggle layout (`ng-include`) when scope model changed, and `ui-view` inside does not load  initially.
But if I toggle twice - all ok.

I think, that I doing something completely wrong, but can't to understand what.

Comment: It is **not** an `ngView`. It is an `uiView`. Please, change the question to prevent confusion.